# Entity Framework Core missing view support

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have read up on the lacking view support in entity framework core. But i wonder what the best way around this is?

I have seemed to find a few ways to go around it.
Like making a entity class as a table for the view, but this will lead to manual work to remove them beeing included in the migrations.

It seems like theres a way to avoid the migrations to add them by doing:

```
      if (IsMigration){
    modelBuilder.Ignore<YourViewTable>();
}
```

The IsMigration variable were supposed to be a static property in the dbcontext set default to true, and in the startup.cs set it to false in the configuration method.

But is this the best way of handling it?

Is it any news of the support for views in EF Core?

Comment: Just curious: Why are you using a view? Most of the time they are not needed and are used to correct db architecture flaws.

Comment: The company i work for have quite a lot of them already